# Specifying environment variable for k8s pvc for storage size

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

Is there a way to specify environment variables in a persistent volume claim in kubernetes for the storage size?

e.g. something like that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pvc
  namespace: devops
spec:
  storageClassName: openebs-local
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: ${JENKINS_PV_SIZE}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Operating System wasn't mentioned, I'll assume linux/macos.

You can use `envsubst` to substitute the variables mentioned in the manifest with the ones set in the Environment and feed the output to `kubectl`:

```
envsubst < pvc.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: great idea ... Thank you